# iPhone app, data layers, & database servers

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, ruby, layer

I found a lot of similar questions out there but none that really answered specifically some of the questions I have. I will be working on an iPhone app shortly that will be accessing data from a database server running windows sql server. I'm not sure what language would be best do write the API in. I prefer Ruby on Rails, but I've read that there are hurdles setting it up with sql server. We could do the API in .net, but I've heard that setting up JSON is a bit of a pain.

What do you suggest? And if I'm doing this the wrong way, let me know the best way. I'm sure most of this is just up to personal preference but I'd love some input.

Comment: We don't really encourage "what do you suggest" questions here - it's too vague, invites discussion/point of view style answers. Perhaps make it a little pointier? "I've heard that..." is another red flag. After all that, I'd suggest ASP.Net MVC - it has a specific WebAPI project type.

Comment: Understood. I'm new here so thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have much idea about building a JSON api in .NET, but if you are planning to use rails there are couple of options to connect to a SQL Server database from Rails.

a) Use JRuby and a jdbc driver like jTDS .  I do want to mention that JRuby is a tad slow when running specs as bootstrapping the rails environment every time takes longer compared to MRI. (this experience based on working in a project couple of years ago, so please try it on your own).

b) Use the MRI ruby with [tiny_tds](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check some of these out and report back with my findings!